# Using degree symbol in Label Expressions of ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, python-parser, regular-expression

I am trying to use the labeling process to display latitude and longitudes for a set of data points.  To make the labels appear formal, I wish to add the degree symbol (°) to the labels.  My python syntax goes as follows:

[lat] + "," +" " + [long] and the result is 30.392634, -91.118229.

However, when I attempt to insert the symbol as follows:

[lat] + "°" + "," +" " + [long] + "°" I keep receiving an error.

I am not a code wizard.

Comment: What is the error message that you receive?

Comment: What version of ArcMap?  What error message do you get?  I get no error message - it works fine for me - but I am using ArcGIS 10.6.  It may be something that has been fixed recently?

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

`[lat] + u'\u00B0' + ', ' + [long] + u'\u00B0'`

Answer (score 2):

I know that you specified that you want to use Python for the labelling, but for a short term work around, why not use VBScript?

[lat] & "°, "& [long] & "°"

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Arcmap python has unicode support so you can use the unicode `\u00B0` to enter it.

```
u"str({0})+'\u00B0  '+str({1})+'\u00B0'".format('!lat!','!long!')
```

Comment: This works if you get rid of all the str(), +, and single quotes