# Create label from different fields in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, expression

I want to create label like this one in ArcGIS Desktop 10.3.1.

[image]

Is there anyway to create label like this?

Each data come from different field.

I can create a label with box or a number with degree. But what I'm looking for is how to stack label like in the example with the automatic resize of the box depends on charactor width.

Can I create label like this in one label not from an annotation by typing and rotate manually?

**Now I can create the label. By using the label expression and use split callout for text background to create the box but the problem is when I increase or reduce font size the box margin does not fit the charactor. Is there anyway better than this?** 
[image]

[image]

[image]

This what happen when I increase the font size.
[image]

when I reduce the font size, box doesn't fit the charactor
[image]

and my label expression is
`[MFA] + vbnewline + [track01] + "° " + [IDENT] + " " + [track02] + "°" + vbnewline + [DIST]`

Comment: I'm fairly confident that it can be achieved but there are several aspects you need to solve to get there e.g. using degree symbol in label, rotating label along line, masking line behind label, adding border to label, stacking labels.  I think you should decide which one you are stuck on first and ask about just that in this question.

Comment: You will then be able to present a label expression that gets you so far towards your goal and ask your next question about where you next get stuck.  We have already had a Q&A on using degree symbols in ArcMap label expressions at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/265368/using-degree-symbol-in-label-expressions-of-arcmap

Comment: You say that you "can create a label with box or a number with degree" so I think that you should detail how you are doing this so that we can see where you are up to and how you got there.  Placing the label along a line will be a labelling property rather than a label expression.

Comment: What is in your label expression?

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested information.  I would use the Python Parser rather than vbScript for the expression and would look at [so] for how to use Python to measure the length of the string returned from your IDENT field to create an appropriate number of spaces either side of it.

Comment: I understand what you said about counting the length of IDENT character but I think the problem is the box is depend on margin not font size so when I reduce or enlarge it, the box is not fit like the regular one. If I had another choice to create the box it will be great.